# Generic and non-generic method overload rules with type inference

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

Given the following two overloaded method signatures:

```
public B DoSomething<A,B>(A objOne, B objTwo)
public object DoSomething(object objOne, Type objType);
```

I would expect that calling this would call the second signature, but it does not:

```
var obj = new SomeType();
var type = typeof(SomeOtherType);

DoSomething(obj, type);
```

It seems to me that looking at the spec, the second overload is more applicable (has one exact type and lesser arity). But, it does not get called. Instead, the first overload is called with A as the type `object` and B as the type `Type`. Why is that and is there a way to call this method aside from either renaming the method or using named parameters?

EDIT:

Here are the parts of the spec I'm referring to in 7.5.3.2:

In case the parameter type sequences {P1, P2, …, PN} and {Q1, Q2, …, QN} are equivalent (i.e. each Pi has an identity conversion to the corresponding Qi), the following tie-breaking rules are applied, in order, to determine the better function member.

- If MP is a non-generic method and MQ is a generic method, then MP is better than MQ.
- ...
- Otherwise, if MP has more specific parameter types than MQ, then MP is better than MQ. Let {R1, R2, …, RN} and {S1, S2, …, SN} represent the uninstantiated and unexpanded parameter types of MP and MQ. MP’s parameter types are more specific than MQ’s if, for each parameter, RX is not less specific than SX, and, for at least one parameter, RX is more specific than SX:

  - A type parameter is less specific than a non-type parameter.
  - ...

Comment: Is there more information you can add to the question? I ran the code in LinqPad and the non-generic overload was used. The code shown (+smallest amount necessary to compile) does not reproduce your issue.

Comment: See @Jon Skeet's answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368252/generic-method-resolution/).

Comment: @hunch_hunch I'm not sure the case is quite the same here.

Comment: @anthony-pegram Sorry, I should not have made obj the type of object. I have updated the question to more accurately reflect the issue.

Comment: Well, if the type isn't object, then it's entirely understandable the generic overload is called, as it matches exactly and the non-generic overload does not.

Comment: I'm not sure the spec reflects that. In 7.5.3.2:

In case the parameter type sequences {P1, P2, …, PN} and {Q1, Q2, …, QN} are equivalent (i.e. each Pi has an identity conversion to the corresponding Qi), the following tie-breaking rules are applied, in order, to determine the better function member. 
• If MP is a non-generic method and MQ is a generic method, then MP is better than MQ.

Maybe C# doesn't consider the conversion to object to be an identity conversion in the way the spec states, I'm not sure.

Comment: Also: • Otherwise, if MP has more specific parameter types than MQ, then MP is better than MQ. Let {R1, R2, …, RN} and {S1, S2, …, SN} represent the uninstantiated and unexpanded parameter types of MP and MQ. MP’s parameter types are more specific than MQ’s if, for each parameter, RX is not less specific than SX, and, for at least one parameter, RX is more specific than SX:
o A type parameter is less specific than a non-type parameter.

Comment: My answer was downvoted to hell but I did test it and it does work.  `DoSomething((object)"1234", typeof(string))`  The cast provides the compiler sufficient information to cause it to select that overload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edit here is methods for compiler to choose between

```
DoSomething<SomeType,Type>(SomeType o, Type t)
DoSomething(object o,Type t);
```

As specification says about picking better function member:

> Given an argument list A with a set of argument expressions { E1, E2,
>   ..., EN } and two applicable function members MP and MQ with parameter
>   types { P1, P2, ..., PN } and { Q1, Q2, ..., QN }, MP is defined to be
>   a **better function member** than MQ if
>   • for at least one argument, the
>   conversion from EX to PX is better than the conversion from EX to QX.

Generic method have better conversion from `SomeType` to `SomeType` than non-generic's method conversion from `SomeType` to `object`. If non-generic method would be defined as

```
DoSomething(SomeType o, Type t);
```

then there would not be any arguments with better conversion, and you'll fall into case:

> In case the parameter type sequences {P1, P2, …, PN} and {Q1, Q2, …,
>   QN} are equivalent

Where first rule would pick non-generic method:

> • If MP is a non-generic method and MQ is a generic method, then MP is
>   better than MQ.

---

NOTE: Before you edited question, there was first argument of type `object`, and generic method was

```
DoSomething<object,Type>(object o, Type t)
```

And again, parameter sequences are equivalent in this case, and non-generic method is picked.

Comment: While I feel that inferred types should be lower on the resolution tree, I see what you're saying about the compile time signature of the generic version.

Answer (score -2):

In my test, I was able to use a cast to get the resolution you want.  `DoSomething((object)"1234", typeof(string));`

Comment: That cast is a no-op in the OP's code; it uses the non-generic overload in the code shown even without the cast.  You had to change the compile time type of the first parameter to something other than `object` for the other overload to have been chosen.

Comment: My suggestion applies correctly to the edited question.  It does not apply correctly to the original unedited question.

Comment: While this works, I would like to avoid boxing that variable here.

Comment: @Nishmaster So that type is a struct?  If so, you'll need to use generics to avoid boxing.  If it's not, then it's not being boxed.

Comment: In your sample code, you are calling a method that takes an object parameter, so you cannot avoid boxing if you call with a value type.  If you call with a reference type, no boxing will take place.

Comment: You folks are correct, I'm not exactly sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score -3):

Call 
    `DoSomething<object, SomeType>(obj, type)();`

Comment: I am not able to do that as I don't know the type at compile time.