# C# extension method resolves to wrong class

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, overload-resolution

Consider this code:

```
public static class Class1
{
    public static string Test(this string t) => "string";
    public static string Test<T>(this T t) => "t";
    public static string Test<U>(this List<U> list)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        list.ForEach(s => result.Append($"{s.Test()},"));
        return $"List({result.ToString()})";
    }

    public static void X()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hallo".Test()); // "string"
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(new Y().Test()); // "t"
        var YList = new List<Y>();
        YList.Add(new Y());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(YList.Test());   // "List(t,)"
        var stringList = new List<string>();
        stringList.Add("Hallo");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(stringList.Test());  // "List(t,)" !!
    }
}
```

IMO the last case should output "List(string,)" because it is called for a List<string> and there is a more specific extension method string.Test(). What am I doing wrong? How to solve this problem?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto There is s.Test() call inside this List<U> list method. So stack should be "Test<List<string>> -> Test", but instead it's "Test<List<string>> -> Test<string>"

Comment: C# generics unlike c++ templates compiled once for all types that satisfy restrictions. As result only thing known at compile time is “u is object”. There should be a good duplicate explaining that in details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic Method Resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368252/generic-method-resolution)

Comment: So I understand that the compiler will not (unlike C++) generate specialized methods for every U in Test<U> that it encounters. In the example above, when I add an extension method public static string Test(this List<string>) with exactly the same method body, it works. Hmm... not exactly generic, but doable.